# Utilizing $('Selector').each to set different variables on each submit

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/EWILL3532/qtyEC/11/

I need help with implementing this:

```
$('selector').each();
```

I'm trying to get this script to set the value of each input to a unique variable each time a submit button is clicked. You'll see that right now, on each submit, the value for the previous question gets alerted - which is what I would be setting as the variable which would be unique to each question.

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just push every item to an array everytime you select an item, leaving you with a unique reference (index) to every value like so:

```
var array = [];
$('button').click(function () {
    var $p = $(this).closest('.ques');
    var val = $p.find(':checked').val();
    if (val === 'Non-Profit or Group' || val === 'Individual') {
        $('.q3').remove();
    }
    alert(val);
    array.push(val);
    $('.ques').hide();
    $p.next().fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uh2CT/)